# Function to determine if a set is subset of another one

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I was quite surprised that Mathematica does not provide built-in operators to determine whether a set is subset of another one.

I mean, I have tried to find a built-in a solution to this problem but actually didn`t succeed.

Which one is the fastest way to reach this goal in Mathematica?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, given two sets `A` and `B`, `A` is a subset of `B` precisely when their intersection equals `A`.  Since Mathematica has the [`Intersection[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ListsAsSets.html) function, you can use that.  Similarly, you could see whether or not there are any elements in [`Complement[A,B]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Complement.html), etc.

Comment: Yeah, what if I told you that I was just thinking to that? Sorry feel so stupid for asking such an obvious question, I didn`t spend just a few minutes thinking about that before creating the question. However thanks a lot for you effort :)